# Java Spring JSON parse Error when converting to Java Array

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, parsing

I've been trying to send a list of Java Objects through a REST Service, but whenever I try to convert it back to a Java Array, I get a JSON parse error:

```
2018-06-10 10:50:08.044  WARN 13680 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 
   Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
   JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of com.master.entity.Greeting[] out 
   of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is 
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize 
   instance of com.master.entity.Greeting[] out of START_OBJECT token
   at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1e32b2a; line: 1, column: 1]
```

This is the Greeting class:

```
public class Greeting {

private final long id;
private final String content;

public Greeting() {
    id = 0;
    content = "something";
}

public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

The REST response method:

```
@RequestMapping("/getlist")
public List<Greeting> getList(Model model) {
    List<Greeting> greetings = new ArrayList<>();
    greetings.add(new Greeting(1, "Something"));
    greetings.add(new Greeting(2, "Something"));
    greetings.add(new Greeting(3, "Something"));
    greetings.add(new Greeting(4, "Something"));
    return greetings;
}
```

My request method:

```
public void restGet() {
    String url = "http://192.168.0.11:8080/greeting";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    ResponseEntity<Greeting[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Greeting[].class);
    Greeting[] greeting = responseEntity.getBody();
    for (int i = 0; i < greeting.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n id: " + greeting[i].getId());
    }
}
```

And this is the JSON string:

```
[{"id":1,"content":"Something"},{"id":2,"content":"Something"},{"id":3,"content":"Something"},{"id":4,"content":"Something"}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your route in the controller is '/getlist', but your are calling '/greeting' in your `restGet` method. Can you verify that you are calling the right route?

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I use this method for a single object as well and forgot to change the URL. Thank you for your answer! I should've thought about it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the URL to the correct one as raiyan suggested and it works fine now.